# How to detect mismatch before mapping in RNA-Seq data

Tags: scrnaseq, read-mapping, reads, barcode

In the methods of [this paper](http://science.sciencemag.org/content/360/6385/176), the authors say:

> Reads were then filtered based on quality score in the UMI region. Any read with >1 low-quality base (phred <=10) were discarded. **Reads with more than one mismatch in any of the three 8 nt cell barcodes were also discarded**. The cDNA reads (Read 1) were then mapped to either a combined mm10- hg19 genome or the mm10 genome using STAR (44).

I understand how to filter based on mismatch *after* mapping but in this case it is done *before* mapping. Has this to be interpreted as "Reads with *low quality in more than one base* in any of the three 8 nt cell barcodes were also discarded"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At each step in the SLiTing and pooling the barcodes added are not random, but are taken  from a predefined list of possible barcodes.

When the reads arrive, first you filter by reads that have >1 low quality bases in the UMI region (which is truely random).

Then you compare the sequences in the 3 cell-barcode regions against the list of allowed barcodes for each of those positions. If a read is not within an edit distance of one from one of those barcodes, it is discarded.

Finally the reads that pass these filters can be aligned.

Answer (score 1):

It should not be interpreted as "Reads with low quality in more than one base in any of the three 8 nt cell barcodes were also discarded". They only care if the cell barcodes match what are valid cell barcodes within 1 mismatch, the individual qualities are ignored. This sort of filtering turns out to be pretty common in practice, since you have to write a maximum edit distance into whatever you use to demultiplex by cells (or labeling each read, as was likely done in this case).

Answer (score 0):

Cell barcodes =/= sequence reads.  The default settings on Illumina's bcl2fastq work exactly the same way; they allow a read to count for a sample if there is a single mismatch in the index, but not more.